# Connection issue between amazon developer account and amazon vendor account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have complete my profile into amazon developer account so when i connecting amazon vendor account
and when i click on integeration iam getting error
Something went wrong
You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this operation. Please ensure that you have completed the Developer Registration and Assessment Process, and that the app you are trying to update is associated with your developer ID.

I am expecting do not get the above error